# Firebase cloud function, Get last added child

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get last added child in cloud function. Here is the code. I want to ask if there is any function or query available to get last added child.
Here is my code:

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('aaa-fff/searchIndex')
    .onWrite(event => {
   // all records after the last continue to invoke this function
   console.log(event.data.val());
   console.log(event.data.numChildren());
});
```

PS. I don't want to loop children.

Comment: This is not exactly what you need but I think it can help you: https://gist.github.com/MiroHibler/4740915

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not precisely sure what your use-case is, but this will get you the last child:

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('aaa-fff/searchIndex')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
   // all records after the last continue to invoke this function
   var lastChild;
   change.after.forEach(function(child) {
       lastChild = child;
   });
   console.log(lastChild.val());
});
```

Comment: I don't want loop, the iteration will be 1 million times if number of children are 1 million.

Comment: Your code is triggered for any change in `/aaa-fff/searchIndex` and will receive all of `/aaa-fff/searchIndex`. With a million child nodes, the loop won't be the expensive part. If you only want to be triggered for new child nodes, you should trigger one level deeper `aaa-fff/searchIndex/{pushid}`. See this section in the docs for examples of this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data

Comment: actually this code give an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at exports.helloWorld.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/srv/index.js:16:15)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:119:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

what is the update code to get the last child add?

Comment: Updated. Also see the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value